# With a Promise is there a mechanism to access the final return value in a .then() chain?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

**Question:** With a `Promise` is there a mechanism to access the final return value in a `.then()` chain?

**Background** I need to run a series of checks/adjustments on an object.  A few of the checks are asynchronous for example comparing data against stored data in mongodb.  Because some checks are asynchronous I believe a `Promise` chain may be the correct option.  However because the checks must be done in a specific order `Promise.all()` will not work.  If a `Promise` chain is a possibility after all of the checks and adjustments have been made I'm not sure how to retrieve the object from the last `.then()` in the chain.  Perhaps I'm approaching this problem with the wrong tool.

The following code is a simplified example.  *myObject* passes through the chain of `.then()` statements but I'm not sure how to retrieve the final, updated object or if that's even possible.

```js
function promisesPromises() {
        return new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {
            let x = {
                name: 'super duper',
                randomDataOne: 10000,
                randomDataTwo: 5000
            };
            if (x) {
                resolve(x);
            } else {
                reject('uh oh');
            }
        }); 
    }

    function firstAdjustment(myObject) {
        myObject.randomDataOne += 1000;
        return myObject
    }

    function secondAdjustment(myObject) {
        myObject.randomDataTwo += 500;
        return myObject;
    }

    promisesPromises()
        .then(firstAdjustment)
        .then(secondAdjustment);
```

Comment: `promisesPromises()
        .then(firstAdjustment)
        .then(secondAdjustment).then(result => console.log(result));` - tada - you've accessed the final result

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes the final value would be myObject after every adjustment has been made in the .then() chain.  In the real version it will probably be 8 or 10 .then() blocks.

Comment: with 8 .thens ... `promisesPromises().then(firstAdjustment).then(secondAdjustment).then(thirdAdjustment).then(fourthAdjustment).then(fifthAdjustment).then(sixthAdjustment).then(seventhAdjustment).then(eighthAdjustment).then(result => console.log(result));`

Comment: @JaromandaX Spitting the final data out to the console is no problem.  But I'm not sure how to return the data.

Comment: "return" it where? you USE it in the `.then` - it's not (safely) usable outside the asynchronous .then chain ... due to asynchrony

Comment: `firstAdjustment` doesn't return a promise, so this isn't a promise chain.

Comment: @JaromandaX You must be right, I hadn't thought about Async.  In theory I can't know when the data will be returned and so it can't be used outside the `.then() ` chain.  It always has to be inside.

Comment: @Barmar, `firstAdjustment` doesn't need to return a promise for this to be a promise chain. Why would it?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 What's the point of using `.then()` if it doesn't return a promise?

Comment: @Barmar, well yes but a promise chain is still a promise chain even if every then callback in it returns value not Promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give `async/await` a try to simplify things.

Note: async functions always return a promise. So in order to get to the data you need to `await` for the returned data inside another async function, or you need to use `then()`. I have given both examples in the code below.

```js
function promisesPromises() {
  return new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {
      let x = {
          name: 'super duper',
          randomDataOne: 10000,
          randomDataTwo: 5000
      };
      // Promise set to resolve after 5 seconds
      if (x) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(x);
          }, 5000)
      } else {
          reject('uh oh');
      }
  }); 
}

function firstAdjustment(myObject) {
  myObject.randomDataOne += 1000;
  return myObject
}

function secondAdjustment(myObject) {
  myObject.randomDataTwo += 500;
  return myObject;
}

const asyncFunction = async () => {
  const myObject = await promisesPromises()
  firstAdjustment(myObject)
  secondAdjustment(myObject)
  return myObject
}

// Example retrieving data with then()
asyncFunction().then(res => console.log("Example using then(): ", res))

// Example retrieving data inside async function
const anotherAsyncFunction = async () => {
  const result = await asyncFunction()
  console.log("Example using async(): ", result)
}

anotherAsyncFunction()

// Timer countdown to promise resolve
let count = 1

const timer = setInterval(() => {
  console.log(count++)
  if (count > 4) clearInterval(timer)
}, 1000)
```

Comment: Thanks your way works!  But I didn't realize until I read a comment from @JaromandaX that even if I can get the return value out I can't use it safely in regular sync code because I can't predict how long the async portion will take.  I learned a ton from this question!

Comment: @stackedAndOverflowed Using `async/await` gives you more control. When you `await`, the code pauses at that point before continuing. To demonstrate this I've updated the code so that the promise resolves after 5 seconds have passed. As you will see, the `console.log()` inside `anotherAsyncFunction()` doesn't trigger until a resolved promise from `asyncFunction()` has been returned. This gives you a lot of power in manipulating data received from API calls.